# Can I customise the looking of table of contents by adding chapters that do not exist in reality?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, pdf, pdfpages

I'm inserting 2 pdf together, one with latex code at the runtime moment, the other one is generated and inserted.
I want to manually add the second table of content of second PDF and merge it to the first PDF in the same place.
Is that possible ?
Like inserting chapters in table of contents with page numbers and the chapter isn't existing in reality ?
Like a static fake link.

Comment: How much of the other pdf do you have?  Is it just the pdf, or its tex source (along with its aux and toc files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most manual approach would be to add each individual entry to the table of contents.  `\addtocontents{toc}{stuff}` will add `stuff` to the toc file, so then it's just a question of what to add (and what to `\protect`).  One example would be
`\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{1}Other Chap}{18}}`
Consult your other toc files for more ideas.

If you have the toc file from the other pdf, then you can automate the process by reading in that toc file but adjusting the page number before writing the contents line.

The following example implements both of these methods: it has three regular entries and then three manual entries to its toc.  Then it reads a different file's toc (actually a copy of itself), but shifts all page numbers by 30 from what's written in the toc.

```tex
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
{
 \newcounter{savepage}
 \let\oldcontentsline=\contentsline
 \renewcommand{\contentsline}[3]{%
  \setcounter{savepage}{#3}%
  \addtocounter{savepage}{30}%
  \oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\arabic{savepage}}%
 }%
 \input{extraTocB.toc}
}

\chapter{Chap Title}
\section{Sect Title}
\subsection{Subsect Title}

Some text.

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Other Preface}{17}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{1}Other Chap}{18}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{1.1}Other Sect}{21}}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(Finally, if you're using hyperref, be aware that it redefines `\contentsline`, so you'll need to adjust everything I've done.)

Answer (score 1):

`addtotoc` looks like it expects to just add a single entry into the table of contents, but would be a pain for something complex. I'm thinking that if the other document is generated by LaTeX, you could do something like

```
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{other.aux}}%
\makeatother
```

right before the pdf pages include and, if all goes well, it should enable you to merge the table of contents information from the two documents.

(Note, the above is untested speculation—I don't have a working LaTeX system at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question in your title but I can't help with your problem as stated in the text.

```
% fakechapterprob.tex  SE 575930

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
% put a fake chapter in the ToC
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{9\hspace{0.5em} Fake}
\chapter{Second}
\end{document}
```

The `\addcontentsline` is a basic LaTeX macro. the `\hspace{0.5em}` is to make the fake chapter's title align with the real chapter titles (might require adjusting according to your particular ToC set of entries).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, just one little thing missing, when I click into the chapter I want that I get directed to the exact page of the second PDF and not to the previous chapter which is not fake